# Nested Loop Problem/ Looped 2 times and also running default in switch case

Tags: java, jconsole

I Have a problem about my nested loop. Every time i request to show a specific data type it will show it but the problem is. it always double the output. How to i stop it? any also the Else showed too. i search all nested solution overhere but i don't see a similar code solution in my code. or any similarity answer for my code.

> NOTE: Im new in Programming JAVA and this is my first Project so please be patient on me and explain everything what i did wrong and where i get this error/bug :) Thank you in advance

Here the code

```
case '2':
            System.out.print("Enter Subject: ");
            SB = buff.readLine();

            File readSUB = new File("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\subject.txt");
            File readN = new File("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\name.txt");
            File readSN = new File ("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\studNo.txt");
            File readSEC = new File("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\section.txt");
            File readTD = new File ("E:\\Onceng Files\\JAVA GROUP PROJECT\\TimeDate.txt");
            Scanner scaSUB = new Scanner(readSUB);
            Scanner scaN = new Scanner(readN);
            Scanner scaSN = new Scanner(readSN);
            Scanner scaSEC = new Scanner(readSEC);
            Scanner scaT = new Scanner(readTD);
            while(scaSUB.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = scaSUB.nextLine();
                SUBJECT.add(s);
            }

            while(scaN.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = scaN.nextLine();
                NAME.add(s);
            }

            while(scaSN.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = scaSN.nextLine();
                STUDNO.add(s);
            }

            while(scaSEC.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = scaSEC.nextLine();
                SECTION.add(s);
            }

            while(scaT.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = scaT.nextLine();
                TIME.add(s);
            }

            System.out.println("Attendance List by SUBJECT: "+SB);
            System.out.println("SUBJECT\t\tNAME\t\t\tSTUDENT NO.\t\tTIME & DATE");
            for(int x=0;x<SUBJECT.size();x++) {
                if(SB.equals(SUBJECT.get(x))) {
                    System.out.println(SUBJECT.get(x)+"\t\t"+NAME.get(x)+"\t\t"+STUDNO.get(x)+"\t\t"+TIME.get(x));
                } else
                    System.out.println("No Record of "+SB+" Subject");
            }

            break;
```

and here the OUTPUT

```
    @#@#@#@#@ MENU @#@#@#@#@
[1] LOGIN ATTENDANCE
[2] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SUBJECT
[3] SHOW ATTENDANCE BY SECTION
[4] SHOW ALL RECORD
Input Number: 2
Enter Subject: JAVA
Attendance List by SUBJECT: JAVA
SUBJECT     NAME            STUDENT NO.     TIME & DATE
No Record of JAVA Subject
No Record of JAVA Subject
No Record of JAVA Subject
JAVA        Saludaga Joshua     19-01297        Tue, 12/03/2019 18:02
JAVA        Pulano Hardhie      19-00900        Tue, 12/03/2019 18:02
JAVA        Tatoy Cherrylyn     19-00751        Tue, 12/03/2019 18:02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for(int x=0;x<SUBJECT.size();x++) {
            if(SB.equals(SUBJECT.get(x))) {
                System.out.println(SUBJECT.get(x)+"\t\t"+NAME.get(x)+"\t\t"+STUDNO.get(x)+"\t\t"+TIME.get(x));
            } else
                System.out.println("No Record of "+SB+" Subject");
        }
```

above should be written as.

```
boolean found = false;
        for(int x=0;x<SUBJECT.size();x++) {
            if(SB.equals(SUBJECT.get(x))) {
                System.out.println(SUBJECT.get(x)+"\t\t"+NAME.get(x)+"\t\t"+STUDNO.get(x)+"\t\t"+TIME.get(x));
found =true;
            }

        }
if(!found)
  System.out.println("No Record of "+SB+" Subject");
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It's Working :D Thank you sir :) . i want to ask again if ok to you sir :)

Comment: i got another problem. if u use the command it will show. but if you try again it double the output. and if you try again now 2 output will become 3 now :( how do i stop the for loop after the code success to execute the code? or how do i reset the value of X in for loop?

Comment: I'm not exactly getting what you are asking for so can please give me example for that. But if you want to stop running loop you can use break;

Comment: wait i place here the output

Comment: See the post sir :( i dont know what i need to do here i can't fix it with my current knowledge on java :( im just a first year student and i dont have so many experience in programming especially in all looping

Comment: I want to help, But not getting your question exactly. that's why I'd request you to provide the `example output` as what is expected and what you are getting right now. So I can help you.